# Flutter Can't Run Project Exited (sigterm)

Tags: flutter

Hello When I run Flutter Project on visual Studio code it doesn't run
its show me the error in this pic

Flutter Can't Run Project Exited (sigterm)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9qJf.png)
flutter clean and flutter pub get, flutter upgrade i use every things

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with flutter 3.10.5. My solution was to add this to AndroidManifest:

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  package="com.example.app"`